# List multicast IP addresses bound to specific device from network driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, multicast

Is there a way to list all the multicast IP addresses bound to a specific device from within a network driver?

I understand how to iterate through a list of multicast MAC addresses through the `net_device` structure using `netdev_for_each_mc_addr()`. I also understand that there is a mapping from multicast MAC to IP, however it's not a 1 to 1 mapping, which is why I'm interested in obtaining the IP multicast groups.

I'm running Centos 7 with a 3.10.0 kernel

The goal is to access this list in `set_rx_mode()` when multicast groups are joined and dropped.

I see that contained in the `net_device` structure is a `struct in_device` and further nested within that is a `struct ip_mc_list`. With that in mind, I tried the following to iterate through the `ip_mc_list`.

```
static void set_rx_mode(struct net_device *netdev)
{
    struct ip_mc_list *ip_list = netdev->ip_ptr->mc_list;

    while(ip_list) {
        printk(KERN_DEBUG " IP MC Address: 0x%x\n", ip_list->multiaddr);
        ip_list = ip_list->next;

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, ip_list remains `NULL` when a Multicast IP address is bound to the device. If this isn't the same `struct in_device` used in the kernel IGMP implementation, is there a way of accessing the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the IP multicast addresses by accessing the `in_device` structure using `in_dev_get(struct *net_device)`. Below is the working code:

```
static void set_rx_mode(struct net_device *netdev)
{
    struct in_device *in_dev = in_dev_get(netdev);
    struct ip_mc_list *ip_list = in_dev->mc_list;

    while(ip_list) {
        printk(KERN_DEBUG " IP MC Address: 0x%x\n", ip_list->multiaddr);
        ip_list = ip_list->next;

    }
}
```